# Change selected cell image uitableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, cell-formatting

I want to change cell image when music is playing , I am using didselectrow for this when i select row it change image and when i scroll i see many other cell image is also changed i don't why please guide me 
here is my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NaatListTableViewCell
            cell?.btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)

    }
```

Comment: Are you writing code blindly? Do you know what is meaning of 'dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier'? Why you are using this method to get cell object in cellForRow method. The problem you are getting is due to this. While scrolling, all cells get reused, instead of creating new instance everytime. if you have changed image on one cell, and then you scroll, when that cell get reused again, that image is going to be shown. So in cellForRow method, please add condition to check if given cell is selected one, then give play image else pause image,

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the image in `didSelectRowAt` method, you can do it another way by implementing **`setSelected(_:animated:)`** method in your custom `UITableViewCell` and handle the image status there, i.e.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if selected {
        btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

The above method handles the selection and de-selection for all the cells in the `tableView` in `single-selection` and `multi-selection` modes.

After this, you'll not need to write anything in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var isPlayingIndex = -1
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NaatListTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == isPlayingIndex {
        cell?.btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
    }else {
        cell?.btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NaatListTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == isPlayingIndex {
        cell?.btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
        isPlayingIndex = -1
    } else {
        // stop current player
        //
        isPlayingIndex = indexPath.row
        cell?.btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain state for your cell manually. You might have some other data associated with your cell, from what you have asked it seems like a list of music files, you could associate with each music a unique id in its model. Now create a map of type `var isPlaying = [Int: Bool]()` (assuming you are going with int ids)

Then in `didSelectRowAt` set the value with corresponding id
`self.isPlaying[YOUR_ID] = cell.isSelected`

Now in your `cellForRowAt` method

```
var imageName = self.isPlaying[YOUR_ID] ? "play" : "pause"
cell?.btnPlayPause.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), for: .normal)
```